# apt-get install build-essential failed with 404 error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

I was trying to install build-essential on a ubuntu 18.04 docker image, I got the following error message:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.
0-43.46_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

It seems that the package dependencies are broken and refer to an old version of linux-libc-dev that no longer exists on the official security updates server.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out.  It's some kind of weird docker thing.  I have a stock official ubuntu image on the system, which was downloaded a while ago.  Now I was trying to build a docker image based on the the stock official ubuntu image. In that Dockerfile, I have "FROM ubuntu:18.04", then RUN apt-get install -y a bunch of packages.  When I tried to build a docker image with that Dockerfile, I got that error message in my original post.  Now, if I docker rmi -f the stock ubuntu image I had on the system, then tried to build a docker image using the SAME Dockerfile, it went all fine.